How to embed enumerated lists, algorithms, pseudocode and flowcharts in a tabular environment
good day.
I want to add listing (bulleted and enumeration), algorithms, pseudo code and flowchart in a tabular environment. For example
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Package used for input and output display.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Graphicx and color.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\section{Problem}
Calculate the gross pay of an employee given the hours worked and the rate of pay.

\textbf{STEP 1: Problem Analysis Chart - PAC}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
 \hline
  \textbf{Given data} & \textbf{Required Results} \\
 \hline
  Hours Pay rate & Gross Pay. \\
\hline
  \textbf{Processing Required} & \textbf{Solution Alternative} \\
\hline
   GrossPay = Hours * PayRate & \begin{itemize}
                                 \item  Define the hours worked 
                                 \item  Data  
                                \end{itemize}                 
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Sorry the code is not looking good.

Ok, thanks, let me reposit again. the objective is to embedd latex code in table environment. for example if I want to list more than one item in the table box, like 1,2,3.

The precise details of how enumerated and itemized lists, flowcharts, and pseudocode algorithms may be embedded in a tabular environment are likely to vary a bit from case to case. One detail they're likely to have in common is that they should be encased in a minipage environment -- with a suitably chosen width. E.g.,

Observe that the options nosep and left=0pt (both provided by the enumitem package) serve to typeset the itemize environment quite compactly; this is usually (always?) desirable if a list needs to be typeset in a cell of a tabular environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less cramped "look"
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Processing required & Solution alternative \\
\hline
$\mathrm{GrossPay} = \mathrm{Hours} \times \mathrm{PayRate}$ & 
% Here comes the embedding of an 'itemize' environment:
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.5cm} % select a suitable column width
  \begin{itemize}[nosep,left=0pt]
    \item Define the hours worked 
    \item Data \strut 
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \\             
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. Be blessed.
